# Why is my data is not binding properly between components?

Tags: angular

`maps.component.ts` sends `title`, `mapItems`, and `displayedColumns` to `summary.component.ts` to be displayed.

The thing is that `title` and `displayedColumns` work correctly, but I'm not too sure why `mapItems` isn't working correctly, that it is not displayed.

If I move `displayedColumns` and `mapItems` outside of the subscribe block, the table is then displayed properly (for both data), but inside the subscribe block only `displayed Columns` is properly passed. So I think something is happening here that I'm not very sure of.

Note: I didn't receive any error messages in my console logs.

Edit: I'm using ELEMENT_DATA as initial testing, eventually I want to pass the data from the get method instead.

Final Edit: Answer solved, please look at my answer below. Problem was with dataSource.

maps.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import { ConfigService } from '../services/config.service';


export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];


@Component({
  selector: 'app-maps',
  templateUrl: './maps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./maps.component.css']
})
export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'maps';
  mapData;
  mapItems: JSON[];
  error: Error;
  displayedColumns: string[]; 

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.displayedColumns = [];

    this.configService.getMaps().subscribe((data) => {

      this.mapData = {
        assetID: "hello"
      };

      this.displayedColumns = ["position", "name", 'weight', 'hello'];
      this.mapItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ELEMENT_DATA));

    }, error => this.error);

  }

}
```

maps.component.html

```html
<app-summary [title]="title" [items]="mapItems [displayedColumns]="displayedColumns"></app-summary>
```

summary.component.ts

```js
export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit {
  addLink: string;
  editLink: string;
  deleteLink: string;

  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() items: JSON[];
  @Input() dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  @Input() displayedColumns: string[];
```

summary.component.html

```html
    <div class="table-container">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <div *ngFor="let col_name of displayedColumns">
                <ng-container matColumnDef={{col_name}}>
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{col_name}} </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item[col_name]}} </td>
                </ng-container>
            </div>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `displayedColumns` is initialised only when the observable returned by `configService.getMaps` emits a value. I assume this does not happen. Do you call `configService.getMaps.emit({})` anywhere?

Comment: I am so sorry, I made a mistake. ```displayedColumns``` is working fine but ```items``` (which is set by ```mapItems```) isn't working. 

If the question is still the same, I don't use emit() anywhere. It's weird though, the observable has to have emitted something since ```displayedColumns``` is working (I've tested it by changing values in ```displayedColumns``` and checking for changes on the website). But it's weird that one is working yet ```mapItems``` isn't.

Comment: Then add in `SummaryComponent` a temporary `ngOnChanges` method and add there and in the subscribe some `console.log` to show the values.

Comment: I've tried this and nothing is logging. But I can verify that ```this.mapItems``` has retrieved the correct values by ```console.log``` right after the line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing displayedColumns inside subscribe method, initialize it while declaring:-

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ["position", "name", 'weight', 'hello'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem. The problem was with the way I was setting up `dataSource`. I realised I didn't add this onto my code, but I was setting its value in `ngOnInit()` with `this.dataSource = this.items`.

The problem is that this only happens once, and I wrongfully thought that data binding would immediately update other functions/variables that depend on the data binding value. Hence I've solved my solution by having my `maps.component.ts` pass in a `dataSource = this.mapItems` in the subscribe block to `summary.component.ts`.